# What is the transformation of uint via RGBA8_SNORM in glTexImage2D-glGetTexImage round-trip?

Tags: c, opengl, textures

I'm trying to understand how a `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` value is transformed into `GL_RGBA8_SNORM` and back using `glTexImage2D` and `glGetTexImage` round-trip. While similar code with `GL_RGBA8` internal format works as expected, I can't seem to understand what's wrong with `GL_RGBA8_SNORM`.

Here's the test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display()
{
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1,&texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
    const GLuint value = 0x60000000;
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA8_SNORM,1,1,0,GL_RED,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,&value);
    GLuint error=glGetError();
    if(error!=GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("TexImage2D failed: %u\n",error);
        exit(1);
    }
    GLuint returned;
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RED,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,&returned);
    error=glGetError();
    if(error!=GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("GetTexImage failed: %u\n",error);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("value: %x, returned: %x\n",value,returned);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
    glutCreateWindow("Texture formats probe");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I get this output:

> value: 60000000, returned: 61616180

I expected the conversion process to be as follows. Initial value of 0x60000000 is divided by `UINT32_MAX` to yield `GLfloat` value of 0.375. Then this result is multiplied by 127 to yield 47.625, which could be rounded to 47 or 48 (depending on hardware). Now one of these rounded values is stored in the texture. On read back this value is divided by 127 to yield 0.370078743 or 0.377952754 (depending of how we rounded when storing to the texture). Then this value is multiplied by `UINT32_MAX`, and upon rounding back we can finally have four possible results:

- 0x5ebd7af5,
- 0x5ebd7af6,
- 0x60c18306,
- 0x60c18305.

Neither of these four is equal to the value I got from `glGetTexImage`. So the conversion process must be somehow different.

I'm testing with a GeForce GTX 750 Ti on Linux 3.12.18 x86_64 with proprietary driver version 375.39.

So what's the actual process of conversion?

Comment: There's no guarantee of the exact internal format. OpenGL docs: "The GL will choose an internal representation that closely approximates that requested by internalFormat, but it may not match exactly."  You'd have to get exact info from GeForce.

Comment: @Gene: Incorrect. `GL_RGBA8_SNORM` is a [required image format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#Required_formats); this means implementations must provide it *exactly* as stated (OK, they're only required to be equal or *better* than it). Now granted, this doesn't mean anything about the conversion operation.